# syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, sql

Hi this is my first post on here so any response would be greatly appreciated. I'm working on a complex php form and keeping getting this error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home2/happyusa/dev/member/rec_id_check.php on line 8

```
<script>
function check_rec_id(obj) {

    if(obj.value.length < 6) {
    document.this_form.recidcheck.value = 'N';
    $('#check_rec_id_msg').html('recID must be over 6 letters');
    $('#check_rec_id_msg').css('color','red');
    return;
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'post', 
    async: true, 
    url: '/member/rec_id_check.php',
    data: 'id=' + encodeURIComponent(obj.value),
    beforeSend: function() {
        //$('#ajax_load_indicator').show().fadeIn('fast'); 
    }, 
    success: function(data) {
        $('#check_rec_id_msg').html(data);
        return;
    },
    error: function(data, status, err) {
        alert('fail to connect to server');
    }, 
    complete: function() { 
        //$('#ajax_load_indicator').fadeOut();
    }
});
return;
}
</script>

<td><input name="rec_uid" type="text" class="input-style" id="rec_uid" style="width:250px; border-color: #0066ff" maxlength="12" onKeyUp="check_rec_id(this)">
```

follow is /member/rec_id_check.php

```
1 
2
3
4
5
6 $rec_uid = trim($rec_uid)
7
8 $sql = "select count(*) from member where uid = '$rec_uid'";
9 $result = mysql_query($sql);
10 $rowcount = mysql_result($result, 0, 0);
11
12 if ($rowcount > 0) {
13    echo "recID is available";
14  echo "<script>$('#check_rec_id_msg').css('color','blue');</script>";
15  exit;
16 }
17
18     elseif ($rowcount = 0) {
19  echo "recID is not available";
20  echo "<script>$('#check_rec_id_msg').css('color','red');</script>";
21  exit;
22 }
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home2/happyusa/dev/member/rec_id_check.php on line 8

My QUESTION
What is wrong? I need your help!!!!

Comment: Look at line 8 and before.

Comment: add ; first to line 6?

Comment: Thx to mario and user2486495

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon (`;`) at the end of line 6:

```
$rec_uid = trim($rec_uid);
```